# UIImageView with fixed height: How can I get the image view width to grow or shrink to match the aspect ratio of the image?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am not supplying code because this is purely a conceptual "how to achieve this" question. But I have listed my attempts and the constraints below.

I've tried a few different strategies to achieve this. Basically, I have variable width images and would like the image to line up perfectly on the left and maintain the 8px spacing with the label on the right. See the images below!

The views themselves are inside a vertical UIStackView. This row a horizontal UIStackView but I've also tried it with a simple UIView container. The only constraint set is on the UIImageView, fixed height of 20px. But I'm looking for any viable strategy to achieve variable width, consistent margins behavior.

I've tried setting the compressionResistence/contentHuggingPriority low on the UIImageView and every combination in between. Is this just not possible?

I've highlighted the background blue to demonstrate the issue

Undesired Behavior: not left aligned, extra space between text
[image: Wrong image: not left aligned, extra space between text]

Desired Behavior: no wasted space, everything lines up
[image: Correct image: no wasted space, everything lines up]

As shown above, the Blue image view is 20 x 40 points, with Content Mode set to Aspect Fit.

How can I get the image view width to grow or shrink to match the aspect ratio of the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a `UIImageView` size to match the image aspect-ratio, you can set the width constraint as a multiple of the height constraint.

If we want an image view to have a Height of 20-points, and an "aspect-fit" Width:

```
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: img.size.width / img.size.height).isActive = true
```

So, let's say we have an image that is `100 x 100` ... we're saying:

- `img.size.width / img.size.height == 1.0`
- `widthAnchor` equals `20.0 * 1.0`
- resulting imageView frame size is `20, 20`

If our image size is `250 x 100`

- `img.size.width / img.size.height == 2.5`
- `widthAnchor` equals `20.0 * 2.5`
- resulting imageView frame size is `50, 20`

Assuming you have a `UIView` subclass where the constraints are setup during init, and you are *then* setting the image, you want to use a "modifiable" constraint as a var / property of your view:

```
class SomeCustomView: UIView {
    
    // we'll update this constraint when the small image is set
    private var smallImageWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

During initial constraint setup:

```
smallImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true

// small image width constraint - will be modified when we set the image
//  small image default is 20x40
smallImageWidthConstraint = smallImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0)
smallImageWidthConstraint.isActive = true
```

When the `.image` is set, we update that constraint:

```
// de-activate
smallImageWidthConstraint.isActive = false

// set width proportional to height to match image aspect ratio
smallImageWidthConstraint = smallImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: smallImageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: img.size.width / img.size.height)

// re-activate
smallImageWidthConstraint.isActive = true
```

Here's a quick example, using these 3 images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In assets, I named them `p272x120`, `p91x200` and `p232x209` since those are the actual image dimensions.

Using this custom view:

```
class SomeCustomView: UIView {
    
    public var bigImage: UIImage? {
        didSet { bigImageView.image = bigImage }
    }
    public var topString: String = "" {
        didSet { topLabel.text = topString }
    }
    public var sideString: String = "" {
        didSet { sideLabel.text = sideString }
    }
    
    // when we set the small image, we also update the width constraint
    public var smallImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            smallImageView.image = smallImage
            // unwrap optional
            if let img = smallImage {
                // de-activate
                smallImageWidthConstraint.isActive = false
                // set width proportional to height to match image aspect ratio
                smallImageWidthConstraint = smallImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: smallImageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: img.size.width / img.size.height)
                // re-activate
                smallImageWidthConstraint.isActive = true
            }
        }
    }

    private let bigImageView = UIImageView()
    private let smallImageView = UIImageView()
    private let topLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .bold)
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    private let subLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    private let sideLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .bold)
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    
    // we'll update this constraint when the small image is set
    private var smallImageWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        // horizontal stack view to hold
        //  small image and side label
        let hStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [smallImageView, sideLabel])
        hStack.spacing = 8
        hStack.alignment = .top

        // vertical stack view to hold labels and ssmall image
        let vStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [topLabel, subLabel, hStack])
        vStack.axis = .vertical
        vStack.spacing = 8

        [bigImageView, vStack].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview(v)
        }

        // small image width constraint - will be modified when we set the image
        //  small image default is 20x40
        smallImageWidthConstraint = smallImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // big image 80x80
            bigImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            bigImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            // leading
            bigImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            // center vertically
            bigImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            // at least 12-points top/bottom
            bigImageView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            bigImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            
            // vStack leading 8-points from big image
            vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bigImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            // center vStack vertically
            vStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            // at least 12-points top/bottom
            vStack.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            vStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            // trailing
            vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            
            // small image height 20-points
            smallImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0),
            // activate the "changeable" width constraint
            smallImageWidthConstraint,
            
        ])
        
        // let's set some properties
        
        backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        
        // edit this after development...

        // big image will be set by controller
        bigImageView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "swift") {
            bigImageView.image = img
        }

        // these will be .clear
        smallImageView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        topLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        subLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        sideLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        
    }
    
    // this is here during development to show
    //  the resulting small imageView size
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // let's use Int values, so we don't output .33333333...
        let w = Int(smallImageView.frame.width)
        let h = Int(smallImageView.frame.height)
        subLabel.text = "Actual size (rounded): (w: \(w), h: \(h))"
    }
    
}
```

and this example controller (putting the custom views in a vertical stack view):

```
class AspectImageVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 20.0

        let myData: [[String]] = [
            ["p272x120", "Wide Image", "Nintendo Switch"],
            ["p91x200", "Tall, Narrow Image", "Left Controller"],
            ["p232x209", "Square-ish Image", "Nintendo Cube"],
            ["", "No Image", "So we can see default 20x40 small image view size"],
        ]

        myData.forEach { d in

            let imgName = d[0]
            let top = d[1]
            let side = d[2]
            
            let someView = SomeCustomView()
            
            if imgName.isEmpty {
                someView.topString = top
            } else {
                someView.topString = imgName + " " + top
                // safely load the image
                if let img = UIImage(named: imgName) {
                    someView.smallImage = img
                }
            }
            someView.sideString = side

            stackView.addArrangedSubview(someView)

        }

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

We get this output:

[image]

---

**Edit** - *in response to comment...*

Views can have more than one of "the same" constraint.

If you want your "small image view" to have a **MAX** width of 40-points...

Add a `lessThanOrEqualToConstant` width constraint:

```
smallImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
smallImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 40.0).isActive = true

// small image width constraint - will be modified when we set the image
//  small image default is 20x40
smallImageWidthConstraint = smallImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0)
smallImageWidthConstraint.isActive = true
```

By default, constraints have `.priority = .required`. So, when we set the image and modify the width constraint:

```
// de-activate
smallImageWidthConstraint.isActive = false
// set width proportional to height to match image aspect ratio
smallImageWidthConstraint = smallImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: smallImageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: img.size.width / img.size.height)
// use less-than-required so we can limit its width
smallImageWidthConstraint.priority = .required - 1
// re-activate
smallImageWidthConstraint.isActive = true
```

So, the `SomeCustomView` with those modifications:

```
class SomeCustomView: UIView {
    
    public var bigImage: UIImage? {
        didSet { bigImageView.image = bigImage }
    }
    public var topString: String = "" {
        didSet { topLabel.text = topString }
    }
    public var sideString: String = "" {
        didSet { sideLabel.text = sideString }
    }
    
    // when we set the small image, we also update the width constraint
    public var smallImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            smallImageView.image = smallImage
            // unwrap optional
            if let img = smallImage {
                // de-activate
                smallImageWidthConstraint.isActive = false
                // set width proportional to height to match image aspect ratio
                smallImageWidthConstraint = smallImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: smallImageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: img.size.width / img.size.height)
                // use less-than-required so we can limit its width
                smallImageWidthConstraint.priority = .required - 1
                // re-activate
                smallImageWidthConstraint.isActive = true
            }
        }
    }

    private let bigImageView = UIImageView()
    private let smallImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return v
    }()
    private let topLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .bold)
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    private let subLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    private let sideLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .bold)
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    
    // we'll update this constraint when the small image is set
    private var smallImageWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        // horizontal stack view to hold
        //  small image and side label
        let hStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [smallImageView, sideLabel])
        hStack.spacing = 8
        hStack.alignment = .center

        // vertical stack view to hold labels and ssmall image
        let vStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [topLabel, subLabel, hStack])
        vStack.axis = .vertical
        vStack.spacing = 8

        [bigImageView, vStack].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview(v)
        }

        // small image width constraint - will be modified when we set the image
        //  small image default is 20x40
        smallImageWidthConstraint = smallImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // big image 80x80
            bigImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            bigImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            // leading
            bigImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            // center vertically
            bigImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            // at least 12-points top/bottom
            bigImageView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            bigImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            
            // vStack leading 8-points from big image
            vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bigImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            // center vStack vertically
            vStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            // at least 12-points top/bottom
            vStack.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            vStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            // trailing
            vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            
            // small image height 20-points
            smallImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0),
            // MAX width of 40-points
            smallImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 40.0),
            // activate the "changeable" width constraint
            smallImageWidthConstraint,
            
        ])
        
        // let's set some properties
        
        backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        
        // edit this after development...

        // big image will be set by controller
        bigImageView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        bigImageView.tintColor = .systemYellow
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "swift") {
            bigImageView.image = img
        }

        // these will be .clear
        smallImageView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        topLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        subLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        sideLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        
    }
    
    // this is here during development to show
    //  the resulting small imageView size
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // let's use Int values, so we don't output .33333333...
        let w = Int(smallImageView.frame.width)
        let h = Int(smallImageView.frame.height)
        subLabel.text = "Actual size (rounded): (w: \(w), h: \(h))"
    }
    
}
```

and the output is now:

[image]

Note that the top image is only 40-points wide, instead of 45 as before.

Comment: In Android, it's just "wrap_content" and you're done! I'm shocked it requires so much work. It gets even more complicated if these images come from the net, but thankfully this is achievable.

Comment: One quick question @DonMag, what if I wanted to apply a maximum aka less than or equal width constraint as well? Say, a maximum width of 40px?

Answer (score -1):

Using DonMag's answer I came up with my own drop in solution. I haven't test edge cases or anything, but it works for my use. I set a fixed height and the content mode to aspect fit in interface builder

```
@IBDesignable
@objc class UIVariableWidthImageView : UIImageView {
    
    override var image: UIImage! {
        get {
            return super.image
        }
        set {
            super.image = newValue
            
            widthConstraint?.isActive = false
            if newValue != nil {
                widthConstraint = self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: newValue.size.width / newValue.size.height)
                widthConstraint?.isActive = true
            }
        }
    }
        
    private var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
}
```